# Display a message when a symbol is missing in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an Excel template for my users to enter data in.

As a precautinary measure, I'd like my template to display an alert message (for a specific column of cells only) if something has been entered by a user but a symbol is missing.

For example: The column 'Email' will contain a list of email addresses that the user must enter. If the user enters an email address that does NOT contain an '@', I'd like an error message to appear telling the user that the email address has not been entered correctly.

As I am still new to Excel VBA, any help on how to build a macro for this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Lots of different ways you could do this.  I'd recommend searching for your answers here.  This is what we call "homework help".  _3.  Questions asking for "homework help" must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._ -[Help Center: What's On Topic Here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -3):

Put the below in the sheet VBA editor:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Emailc As Long

On Error Resume Next
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Find(What:="Email", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
On Error GoTo 0
if Activecell.value = "Email" then Emailc = Activecell.column


If Emailc = 0 Then MsgBox "There's no ""Email"" column - please rename the appropriate column", vbCritical, "No Email column found": Exit Sub
If Target.Column = Emailc Then If Not InStr(Target.Value, "@") Then MsgBox "Invalid email entered" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please ensure email address has an ""@"" symbol", vbCritical, "Invalid address"

Target.activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. However it does not work because when I paste this in the VBA editor and run the macro, I get an alert message even when my Email column (range=I9:I500) contains an email address with an '@'. Also because we have Rows("1:1").Select, every time I enter a value in any cell, the first row is highlighted.

Comment: @Morpheus You need to change the selection. If your search range is between cells I9:I500 then change `Rows("1:1").Select` to `Range("I9:I500").Select`.

Comment: @Jeremy I didn't downvote you, but I can tell you that you got all the downvotes because people don't like when users give answers to questions outside the scope of the Help Center.  This question asks for code/formulas to be written with no indication of any attempt being made.  Just an FYI so you are aware as I see you are a relatively new user.

Comment: @Chrismas007 that's fair - thanks for the heads-up! I have noticed people commenting under questions say "Show me your code" etc and my thoughts on that were while the questioner didn't demonstrate their work done on the problem, I would like to build my profile - that backfired!